# Singleton CRTP with meyers singleton

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, singleton, crtp

i am tring to implement a Singleton template that using meyers singleton inside:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

template <typename T>
class Singleton {
public:
    static T& instance() {
       static T _instance; 
       return _instance;
    }
protected:
    Singleton() = default;
    ~Singleton() = default;
    Singleton(const Singleton & s) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton & s) = delete;
};


class Foo : Singleton<Foo> {
public:
    void print() {
       std::cout<<"from the foo singleton count : " <<count++<<std::endl; 
    }
private:
    int count = 0;

};

int main () {
   Singleton<Foo>::instance().print();
   Singleton<Foo>::instance().print();
   Singleton<Foo>::instance().print();
   return 0;
```

and it seems to work : [link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrWVX0AGTy1MAOWcARpjEIADMvAAOqEKE5rR2ji7KUTFmdF4%2B/k5BIdpGmCZptAwEzMQECc6unPmFcSVlBBl%2BgcFhvEKl5ZVJNZ2NzVk5INoAlEaoDsTIHFIA9HMA1AAqAJ4RmIurk8SLaFiLCMGYpIski6yozOiLaouY4sxOEewAdJoyAII6od7IjgdNKEbAFCEI5p10Fo9AZXgggdgPt8vgRMM9VKjFkCbAR1lYnptlgikf9mEIhIsGN5gOwiLQsQB2fRfCIOAKsPDIEBIxa8xb9MzIFY6ABsi28/VoMwgo0ZzM%2BfMVAs5K0WAH0JaUpZggbosV9FXziJgCFN6RraJKZrqeXzNAyACJIiLEVCo0yYdDcg18qnqWl0GVY0IOxZYKjMBysAg2n28gB%2BfppJsDsqBofDkejsYVvupAdoEDQloIlPzKfpov5aZDYYKJp1oXliqTBarqA2xGYRGI6aLdE6Zf9Fax2jFQhrGfrqJz9qdTaRi6%2BpPJiwAYqhUIsQEPk3TsRvUAi5c62RyubbeQA3VB4G4u7wEIP25uG/kEL0oSYx4HYnTaKhXScRYCCORYaC3GJhzpPZJnobdR20YMbGxNAHHoAxMN/YFIRAEB3FYXV9VzXk52dYg8CvbsOEvcV4LQ%2BD00WGRZy%2BMiFzYr5H0WJxmG8RZnyZS9WwrA9NwRPDNTUaVRleB96BlHM82gugxKPUJsEkktpMwGU5IohTRiU3kRP3YFDwkkApO1PT5KfIyOJI41TWIekWKbYi5ykcZWGkABWeRXFkeRUGkFCYT0fkdhmUdQk4eQCGkORRnGABrMJQleUJspy3LcpFFRpG4QKkpC6R5CEEAZFIRLgvGOBYCQNBnjwdgyAofsWrakBgE4Tg8ioVrUWISqIACUrSFBWgylWaR4tIZqnCsAgAHlaFYWbgtILBeOHCb8GNUxKMwSqtoeTBkAcVEJsfAoJo5AIu2IVY7CwCaCAopw5u8vhVGAIQADU8EwAB3FaNiC%2Bb%2BEYFh2C4XhoeEMRJC2pQalUdQUEwvQVDwAJKsgcYOyKU6AFpIXTaF9D0bQ5FqC6iksawemqUh3EGVoQhqFJYjoFnkmiXnaA57I2j6esjroBpunsKplGMBn6i6JpvBaUWuaMZX%2Bb6ZWReGThxiEaKOANwqpAC0ggrp0KpHEAAOEVSZFbhFmAZAhT614kIgcLqcMRZcEIc4fhqRY7C64JYoNhLSpS0h0u0ThXm4EVQhFGR0%2B4bQGQZGRtD8s3istiabYqqqatj0gGsQEBv1ZAhyEoZqIlasW2fwHtlGhpg2BNhG6AIJGJAmkGuwib6fP8kqtptlarvrs4qEWe3Hed133cWT3vfDlu2qj0YY7qtKQG4PyvZkUIM4z7RQjtgBOZ3C%2Bn63yqMcvauSyepG0Z%2ByqkQ/P6kCvMEGIFhuBAA)

but now i want to be able to using it like this :

```
Foo::instance().print();
```

is there any way to do it ?

Comment: #include <bits/stdc++.h> never use this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: I think you need `class Foo : PUBLIC Singleton<Foo>'

Comment: As an aside, `Foo` is not a true singleton. `Foo` is default constructible in any scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using private inheritance with `class Foo : Singleton<Foo>`  which means to the outside world, `Foo` is not a `Singleton<Foo>` and it doesn't have a `instance` function.  You can add

```
using Singleton<Foo>::instance;
```

To the public section of `Foo`.  That will import the `instance` function into the public space of `Foo` and allow

```
Foo::instance().print();
```

to compile.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the error message that results from trying to call `Foo::instance().print()` because it tells you whats wrong:

```
<source>:30:17: error: 'static T& Singleton<T>::instance() [with T = Foo]' is inaccessible within this context
   30 |    Foo::instance().print();
      |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

`Singleton<T>::instance()` is inaccessible via `Foo::instance()` because `Foo` inherits privately. Make `Foo` inherit publicly and it works.